# How to restrict access to a php file to once per day? (specifically, the php file sends an e-mail, I want one e-mail per day per user/IP)

Tags: php

I have searched around but I am not very experienced with PHP. The script I have at the moment is

```
<?php
 $to = "my email address";
 $subject = "Report for broken link";
 $id= $_GET['id'];
 $body = "Link ID: $id";
 if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
    echo("<p>Message sent!</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
  }
 ?>
```

So basically it is for a user of the site to report a broken link, but I expect this is very easily exploitable as everytime I refresh the .php page an e-mail is sent.

As in the question title, I am looking for a way to limit use of the .php file to once per day (or per x hours) per user. What is the easiest way to do this?

EDIT: or, if you have a better idea for a solution, please let me know!

EDIT AFTER HAVING SOLVED:

For those interested in the solution to this, I have used the following (it seems to work, but if anyone can see any glaring holes in it please post her):

```
<?php
 $to = "my email address";
 $subject = "Report for broken link";
 $id= $_GET['id'];
 $body = "Link ID: $id";
 if(isset($_COOKIE['noaccess'])) {
 echo ("<p>Message already sent!</p>");
  } else {
     if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
       setcookie("noaccess", "2hrs", time()+7200);
       echo("<p>Message sent!</p>");
      } else {
       echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
      } }
 ?>
```

Comment: One suggestion: Use a POST request instead of a GET request. This will foil some would-be in-browser URL manipulators.

Comment: Thanks! I have switched from GET to POST now.

Comment: In fact, changing from GET to POST didn't work. It stopped posting the value of 'id' (done by php query string- ie. ?id=

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12190120/1815624

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could try is after the email is sent store a timestamp in the user session or a browser cookie, and then when the script is invoked again, you can check to see if a timestamp is present and if yes, if it is higher than your email threshold (one day, x hours, etc...)

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the best option for me. I will try using
    setcookie("noaccess", "2hours", time()+7200);
after sending the e-mail and put in some kind of if statement before sending the e-mail. I assume this is how you meant?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of something along those lines.

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet is to create a database table that keeps track of whether a particular user id has accessed the page or not. Once they do, write a row to the table with the date and user id. On each page load, check the table to see if there is a row for the user id and current date, and if so, don't send the email.