# How to restrict user to login more than once a day in php

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to restrict users not to login more that once per day. Is this possible in PHP? if so can you guide me in how to do it?

In my database i have username and password fields and timestamp? What should I add more?

I tried this but the problem is that i don't want it to restrict with *IP* and should be respect to user.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("");

mysql_query("delete from restrict where time >= " . time() + (24*3600));

$result = mysql_query("select * from restrict where ip =\"{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'}\"");

if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
$sql = "insert into restrict values('', '{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}', '" . time() . "')";
mysql_query($sql);
} else {
die("You cannot access this page for 24hrs after you viewed it last...");
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Do you want them to remain logged in for some time, or just view a certain page ONCE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would just query where timestamp is greater than 24 hours ago.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `users` WHERE `timestamp` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)";
```

If there is a result, don't let them in.

This assumes you have a user table with a timestamp field that is updated when a user logs in. I don't know what you're doing with this whole restrict table in your post.

This is a flawed system though. You should be storing a cookie or something in case something goes wrong and they get logged out, something happens, etc, before they are done with whatever you are serving. Course, what do I know without knowing what you're really up to here?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that you should not restrict by IP address.  Some reasons include:

- Some users can just get a new IP address by walking down the street with their smart phone or rebooting their router.
- Some IP addresses are shared by a *great deal* of users.  Some AOL IP addresses are shared by tens of thousands of AOL users (proxy gateway).

If you have a timestamp of last successful login, simply check whether there was a previous login for that user and, if so, how long ago that login was when they attempt to log in.

Keep in mind that nothing in this scheme prevents a user from *staying* logged in for as long as they wish, though they would have to interact with the website (either in person or by using a bot) every so often to prevent the session from timing out).

Answer (score 1):

I'd just add a column like "lastLoginTime" to the login/users/whatever table and update that time whenever the user logs in. Then check it when logging in to see if the time they logged in, lastLoginTime, was within the last 12/24/whatever hours.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can make like you said a separate table

```
id_user | date
```

both integers

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb', 'username', 'password');
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `restrict` WHERE `id_user`=:id_user");
$stmt->execute(array(':id_user' => $_POST['username']));
$exist = $stmt->rowCount();
if(!$exist){
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `restrict` VALUES(:id_user,:date)");
    $stmt->execute(array(':id_user' => $_POST['username']), ':date' => date('Ymd'));
} else {
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if($row['date'] != date('Ymd')){
        $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE `restrict` SET `date`=:date WHERE `id_user`=:id_user)");
        $stmt->execute(array(':id_user' => $_POST['username']), ':date' => date('Ymd'));
    } else {
        die("You already accessed this page today.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create another column called last_login, where you will store the login time. Next time when user tries to log in, check the difference between last_login time and current time and if it is less then 24 hours, restrict the user.